# Dataframe not showing twitter sources from Android

Tags: python, json, pandas, tweepy

I am trying to try to do some analysis on a twitter account, but I am having trouble trying to show sources from Android. What I did was merged two json files and I think I merged it correctly, but incase I got that wrong here is the code I used.

```
old_tweets = load_tweets("real_tweets/real_old_tweets.json")
print(len(old_tweets))  
for aLis1 in old_tweets:
    if aLis1 not in tweets:
        tweets.append(aLis1)
```

load_tweets is a custom function that simply opens and loads a json file given a specific **path**

```
with open(path, "rb") as f:
    import json
    return json.load(f)
```

After merging the two json files of tweets I then called this function to create the data frame and clean it up to only display the information I want.

```
df_tweets1 = pd.DataFrame(tweets)
df_tweets2 = df_tweets1[['id','created_at','source','full_text','retweet_count']]
df_tweets = df_tweets2.drop_duplicates('id', keep=False
df_tweets.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df_tweets = df_tweets.rename(columns={"created_at": "time", "full_text": "text"})
df_tweets["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df_tweets["time"])
```

The problem is that when i call *df_tweets["source"].unique()* I don't see any tweets coming from android

```
array(['<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>',
   '<a href="http://twitter.com/#!/download/ipad" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPad</a>',
   '<a href="https://studio.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Media Studio</a>',
   '<a href="https://studio.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Media Studio</a>',
   '<a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>'],
  dtype=object)
```

Did I do something wrong when merging the two sets of Twitter data? Or did I do something wrong when trying to create the data frame?

EDIT**Here is a sample output from real_old_tweets.json to give a sense of the format. I am only going to post one because there is a lot of information contained in one tweet.

```
[{'created_at': 'Tue Oct 16 16:22:11 +0000 2018',
  'id': 1052233253040640001,
  'id_str': '1052233253040640001',
  'full_text': 'REGISTER TO https://url/0pWiwCHGbh! #MAGA https://url/ACTMe53TZU',
  'truncated': False,
  'display_text_range': [0, 44],
  'entities': {'hashtags': [{'text': 'MAGA', 'indices': [37, 42]}],
   'symbols': [],
   'user_mentions': [],
   'urls': [{'url': 'url/0pWiwCHGbh',
     'expanded_url': 'linkVote.GOP',
     'display_url': 'Vote.GOP',
     'indices': [12, 35]},
    {'url': 'url/ACTMe53TZU',
     'expanded_url': 'linktwitter.com/erictrump/status/1052174007708147714',
     'display_url': 'twitter.com/erictrump/stat…',
     'indices': [45, 68]}]},
  'source': '<a href="linktwitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>',
  'in_reply_to_status_id': None,
  'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None,
  'in_reply_to_user_id': None,
  'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None,
  'in_reply_to_screen_name': None,
  'user': {'id': 25073877,
   'id_str': '25073877',
   'name': 'Donald J. Trump',
   'screen_name': 'realDonaldTrump',
   'location': 'Washington, DC',
   'description': '45th President of the United States of America',
   'url': 'url/OMxB0x7xC5',
   'entities': {'url': {'urls': [{'url': 'url/OMxB0x7xC5',
       'expanded_url': 'linkwww.Instagram.com/realDonaldTrump',
       'display_url': 'Instagram.com/realDonaldTrump',
       'indices': [0, 23]}]},
    'description': {'urls': []}},
   'protected': False,
   'followers_count': 55165024,
   'friends_count': 47,
   'listed_count': 94709,
   'created_at': 'Wed Mar 18 13:46:38 +0000 2009',
   'favourites_count': 25,
   'utc_offset': None,
   'time_zone': None,
   'geo_enabled': True,
   'verified': True,
   'statuses_count': 39296,
   'lang': 'en',
   'contributors_enabled': False,
   'is_translator': False,
   'is_translation_enabled': True,
   'profile_background_color': '6D5C18',
   'profile_background_image_url': 'linkabs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png',
   'profile_background_image_url_https': 'linkabs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png',
   'profile_background_tile': True,
   'profile_image_url': 'linkpbs.twimg.com/profile_images/874276197357596672/kUuht00m_normal.jpg',
   'profile_image_url_https': 'linkpbs.twimg.com/profile_images/874276197357596672/kUuht00m_normal.jpg',
   'profile_banner_url': 'linkpbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/25073877/1539493274',
   'profile_link_color': '1B95E0',
   'profile_sidebar_border_color': 'BDDCAD',
   'profile_sidebar_fill_color': 'C5CEC0',
   'profile_text_color': '333333',
   'profile_use_background_image': True,
   'has_extended_profile': False,
   'default_profile': False,
   'default_profile_image': False,
   'following': False,
   'follow_request_sent': False,
   'notifications': False,
   'translator_type': 'regular'},
  'geo': None,
  'coordinates': None,
  'place': None,
  'contributors': None,
  'is_quote_status': True,
  'quoted_status_id': 1052174007708147714,
  'quoted_status_id_str': '1052174007708147714',
  'quoted_status_permalink': {'url': 'url/ACTMe53TZU',
   'expanded': 'linktwitter.com/erictrump/status/1052174007708147714',
   'display': 'twitter.com/erictrump/stat…'},
  'quoted_status': {'created_at': 'Tue Oct 16 12:26:46 +0000 2018',
   'id': 1052174007708147714,
   'id_str': '1052174007708147714',
   'full_text': 'Friends: Quick reminder that today is that last day to register to vote in Oregon, Kansas, Louisiana, West Virginia, New Jersey and Maryland. It is very quick and easy - simply go to url/GE5BO5ONN1! Let’s #MakeAmericaGreatAgain ',
   'truncated': False,
   'display_text_range': [0, 243],
   'entities': {'hashtags': [{'text': 'MakeAmericaGreatAgain',
      'indices': [214, 236]}],
    'symbols': [],
    'user_mentions': [],
    'urls': [{'url': 'url/GE5BO5ONN1',
      'expanded_url': 'linkwww.Vote.GOP',
      'display_url': 'Vote.GOP',
      'indices': [183, 206]}]},
   'source': '<a href="linktwitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>',
   'in_reply_to_status_id': None,
   'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None,
   'in_reply_to_user_id': None,
   'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None,
   'in_reply_to_screen_name': None,
   'user': {'id': 39349894,
    'id_str': '39349894',
    'name': 'Eric Trump',
    'screen_name': 'EricTrump',
    'location': '',
    'description': "Executive Vice President of The @Trump Organization. Husband to @LaraLeaTrump. Large advocate of @StJude Children's Research Hospital. #MakeAmericaGreatAgain",
    'url': 'url/uwwNiWyamR',
    'entities': {'url': {'urls': [{'url': 'url/uwwNiWyamR',
        'expanded_url': 'linkwww.Trump.com',
        'display_url': 'Trump.com',
        'indices': [0, 23]}]},
     'description': {'urls': []}},
    'protected': False,
    'followers_count': 2191617,
    'friends_count': 715,
    'listed_count': 5736,
    'created_at': 'Mon May 11 21:42:30 +0000 2009',
    'favourites_count': 8638,
    'utc_offset': None,
    'time_zone': None,
    'geo_enabled': True,
    'verified': True,
    'statuses_count': 5601,
    'lang': 'en',
    'contributors_enabled': False,
    'is_translator': False,
    'is_translation_enabled': False,
    'profile_background_color': '000000',
    'profile_background_image_url': 'linkabs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png',
    'profile_background_image_url_link': 'linkabs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png',
    'profile_background_tile': True,
    'profile_image_url': 'linkpbs.twimg.com/profile_images/974045997268529152/R0CuVYHM_normal.jpg',
    'profile_image_url_link': 'linkpbs.twimg.com/profile_images/974045997268529152/R0CuVYHM_normal.jpg',
    'profile_banner_url': 'linkpbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/39349894/1516709628',
    'profile_link_color': '116AB8',
    'profile_sidebar_border_color': '000000',
    'profile_sidebar_fill_color': '616161',
    'profile_text_color': '000000',
    'profile_use_background_image': True,
    'has_extended_profile': False,
    'default_profile': False,
    'default_profile_image': False,
    'following': False,
    'follow_request_sent': False,
    'notifications': False,
    'translator_type': 'none'},
   'geo': None,
   'coordinates': None,
   'place': None,
   'contributors': None,
   'is_quote_status': False,
   'retweet_count': 1945,
   'favorite_count': 3828,
   'favorited': False,
   'retweeted': False,
   'possibly_sensitive': False,
   'lang': 'en'},
  'retweet_count': 5415,
  'favorite_count': 16565,
  'favorited': False,
  'retweeted': False,
  'possibly_sensitive': False,
  'lang': 'en'},
```

Comment: can you include a sample from `real_tweets/real_old_tweets.json`

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure there are sources in the original files that show android? And can you post a sample of one or two of each source?

Comment: @G.Anderson I manually inspected the merged file and did a ctrl-f ("Android") there are instance where it is created there

Comment: @wpercy i just edited my post to show the format of one tweet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are having "android" sources and I don't have a clear idea of how your data looks like and what is the relation between the "id" and source. Having said that, there is a bug when you are preparing your data. You are dropping all the duplicates.

For example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':[1,2,2],'col2':[3,4,3],'col3':[1,4,1]})
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     1
1     2     4     4
2     2     3     1
>>> df.drop_duplicates('col1',keep=False)
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     1
```

In the above code, you can see that it is dropping all the duplicate rows if you use "keep=False".

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates('col1',keep='first')
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     1
1     2     4     4
```

Instead, use *keep='first'* or *keep='last'* and see if there is any improvement. Also, it would be great if I can get more sense of data, to figure out where it is going wrong.

**EDIT**

After some time, I took your JSON object and saved to a "me.json" file in the format of:

```
[{},{}]
```

Where the first object's source is an iPhone and second object's source is android. I used your code for loading in the data:

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import json
>>> with open('me.json','rb') as file:
...     json_list = json.load(file)
... 
>>> len(json_list)
2
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(json_list)
>>> df1 = df[['id','source']]
>>> df1['source'].value_counts()
<a href="linktwitter.com/download/Android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>    1
<a href="linktwitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>      1
Name: source, dtype: int64
```

In the above output, you can see that I am able to see the **"Android"**. My conclusion is that in your data, there might be **no "Android"** at all, in the df['source'] column.

Please see it carefully as there are two **"source"** keys inside each JSON object, one key is inside the **"quoted_status"**. There are chances that you might have seen "Android" in this key.

Comment: I just edited my post with an example of my old_tweets.json

Comment: @onbu Did you try to get the df_tweets2['source'].unique()? Can you see android over there? Kindly let me know.

Comment: that gave me the same result as df_tweets["source"].unique(). I don't see android

Comment: So just out of curiosity i just printed out the information from *tweets* and I found source as Android. So could it be an issue of my merging of the two json files

Comment: Did you mean append when you are saying merge? because append should not be a problem then, I was thinking whether reading in the file is done correctly, what you can do is add two dummy JSON objects is a separate file and try to read in the file, if you still you don't see the android! let me know

Comment: @onbu see the edit above, let me know if problem is resolved

Comment: I really am dum. I had to look far far back because this particular user did not switch over from android until 2 years ago. So i needed to look at data from farther back. Thanks!